# Can't get django-registration to work (on Windows)

Tags: python, django, registration, setuptools, easy-install

Trying to add [django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home) to my app. I have installed [setup tools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) to use [easy_install](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#using-easy-install). I think that works..

I run easy_install django-registation and a cmd prompt window flashes up, does something and closes. I don't think it's an error. But when I look in my app folder, theres nothing relation to django-registration.

Anyone know what is wrong? And where should the django-registration files appear?

(Also tried it with django-profiles and it was exactly the same)

Comment: Instead of running "easy_install django-registration", run "cmd" then type in "easy_install django-registration".  That way you can see the output.

Comment: That is what I do, but it opens another cmd window which flashes up briefly before closing itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django-registration will be installed on your python path, not in the project itself. You can see if it installed correctly by entering your python prompt and running:

```
>>>import registration
```

If you don't get an error it is working and installed. Just add 'registration' to your INSTALLED_APPS.